# Azure Function create folders in the bin-folder?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function (v3):

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "bin", "MyFolder", "TextFile1.txt")))
            return new OkObjectResult("File does exists!");
        else
            return new OkObjectResult("File does NOT exists!");
    }
```

Inside my .csproj is have:

```
<None Update="MyFolder\TextFile1.txt">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

and this:

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">

<ItemGroup>
  <MySourceFiles Include="$(OutDir)\MyFolder\TextFile1.txt" />
</ItemGroup>

<Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\bin\MyFolder\" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

I want `..MyFolder/TextFile1.txt` to be copied to `..bin/MyFolder/TextFile1.txt`

Running this locally it works fine `File does exists!`
But publishing it to Azure i get a `File does NOT exists!`

Looking at the `.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` I can see the folders are not quite as I had hope

```
C:\home\site\wwwroot\MyFolder>
C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin>
```

I did try to add the `<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>` but that didn't help.

How can I make this example work?

(EDIT)
Why I try to do this:
I have a third-party DLL that expect a folder-structure located in the same folder as the DLL is located. This is normally stretch forward in a .NET project.
Using Azure functions this folder-structure is now not placed in the same folder as the DLL.

Comment: can you please try to explain what you are actually trying to achieve? working on local folders/files in Functions is in many cases an anti pattern

Comment: #silent I made an edit with a better explanation of what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the file as `Copy Always`:

```
<None Update="MyFolder\TextFile1.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

In VS, Click on the file > `Properties` > Change `Copy to Output Directory` > `Copy Always`.

---

#### Edit:

In this case, you will have to copy file from `wwwroot` folder to `wwwroot/bin` using Pipeline `Copy file` task.

Comment: That didn't change anything

Comment: It will add your file to your bin folder. I checked it. Can you check if redeployment with this setting adds `TextFile1.txt` file in folder using Kudu or not?

Comment: The problem is that it adds it to:
C:\home\site\wwwroot\MyFolder\TextFile1.txt
and I wants it to be added to:
C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\MyFolder\TextFile1.txt

Comment: Is it not there in bin folder? It should add to bin folder as well.

Comment: I agree it should but it is not

Comment: I checked, in deployed version of Function App, I am not able to see(I could see in Local's bin). My bad. In this case, you will have to copy file from `wwwroot` folder to `wwwroot/bin` using Pipeline `Copy file` task. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: If you want to do it using Kudu console, you can copy/ move that file using Console commands.

Comment: I don't see why this is marked as the answer.
The problem is that Azure Functions builds into a special bin folder, that other project types does not have.
Manually moving some files is not the solution, and also not creating a pipeline task to do it.
Third-party libraries fails because some dll's are in the special bin folder, and some are not.